# Copy folders to new folder with different ending

Tags: unix, rename, directory, cp

I have a huge number of folders all with different names but same ending.
Like this:

```
    blabla_ending1
```

Now I want to copy all those folders and give them another ending (ending2). I tried this but it did not work like I want to:

```
    cp -r *_ending1 *_ending2
```

Somehow I need to specify that the second * depends on the first one. Maybe I am also unaware of the precise meaning of *. I know its very basic but I could not find any help yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a simple command to achieve that. However, the following will achieve the desired result:

```
for path in *_ending1; do
  newpath=`echo $path | sed 's/_ending1$/_ending2/'`
  cp -r $path $newpath
done
```